# different between limit query in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make page number for my table and need to know row count.

for example my query is `SELECT * FROM tbl` and the result is 100rows.

I should limit query to `10rows` for one page.

if I do that I cant get all rows count.

I want to know is there any different between `limit with mysql our php` in process speed.

please tell me if you have any idea.

Comment: The answer depends on your data, but in many cases, executing two SQL queries (one for COUNT, one for LIMIT) will be faster than retrieving and slicing the entire result set. Benchmarking is the way to determine the best solution for your situation.

Answer (score 3):

You shoud use `LIMIT` in your MySQL. Why?

```
*Because it will take you less time to fetch some amount of data and transmit it instead of getting everything.

*Because it will consume less memory.

*Because working with smaller arrays is generally faster.
```

As for me, I used PHP as a filter only when I could not perform the filtering in MySQL

Just to update my answer, as **Joachim Isaksson** already posted:

[SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) will help you count all the rows, so you can perform a correct pagination.

Comment: That's the idea. For any table of non-trivial size, you should be fetching with a `LIMIT` clause. It is impractical to do otherwise. On a table with millions of rows, your application might exhaust all system memory and crash the system.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is probably to use [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) and combine them both;

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl LIMIT 10
```

...to get the first 10 rows as a result. Then you can just do;

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

...to get the total number of rows you would have got if you hadn't used `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you will have 100k rows? Of course, you will get rows count, but performance significantly decrease (and memory usage significantly increase). Just use second query to obtain amount of rows and limit rows in mysql

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your problem ,solution might be like this :Strictly by mysql

- Use two function first for counting total record
- second for getting result
- select count(1) as total from table_name
- select col1,col2.. from table_name limit $start , $slot_size

Now slot_size is number of record you want to show on page,say 10
start is value which will change according to page